# Why explicit parameters for static and dynamic linking

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gnu

I have mostly worked in Windows, and recently I started working in Linux. I have a doubt. I have used Visual Studio as IDE in Windows and used Makefile in Linux.

There are two types of libraries in Windows (VC++), static library (.lib) and DLL. It is quite obvious (isn't it?) if I link with lib file I am using static linking else dynamic linking.

Now when I use g++ compiler, why I need to explicitly mention `-Bstatic/-static` or `Bdynamic/-dynamic` flags. Because if file is .a file then I must be using static -linking and if file is .so I am using dynamic linking.

Comment: For the record, a "doubt" is when you think something is not true. It is not the same as a "question".

Comment: Sometimes a machine has both .a and .so versions of a library.  So -B tells it which one to use.

Comment: Please see [Can "doubt" sometimes mean "question"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2429/can-doubt-sometimes-mean-question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are times when you want to "force" the compiler to do what it normally wouldn't. In particularly -static is useful when you are building against a library that may not be installed [or not have the same version installed] on another machine where you want your code to run.

the -Bdynamic is useful if you want to have ONE library linked statically, but not EVERY library that your code uses.

e.g. `gcc -o myprog myprog.o -Wl,-Bstatic -lspecial -Wl,-Bdynamic`
will link `myprog` using static linking for `libspecial` (which may be something that isn't widely distributed, for example something you have built yourself)

For general, local development, you don't need either.

Comment: Thanks Mats, detailed explanation!

Answer (score 0):

In the GNU toolchain, and other Unix compilers, you generally don't specify the full path to a library; you give the linker a flag such as

```
-lfoo
```

and let it figure out whether it should link with `libfoo.a`, `libfoo.so`, and where these files are located. When only a static library is available, it will link with that.

So, you don't really need to specify `-Bstatic` except in a few specific cases. Dynamic linking is the default and if you don't want a custom library to be linked dynamically, then just don't build a `.so` out of it.

Besides, you *can* explicitly link with a static library by giving the full filename to the linker

```
gcc -o some_binary main.o libfoo.a
```

to get a dynamically linked binary with `libfoo` statically linked in.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got it backwards.  Whether I'm linking with
a dynamic library or with a static one, under Windows, I need
a `.lib` file; they just aren't generated in the same manner,
and don't contain the same thing.  Under Unix, when I link with
a shared object, I link directly against the `.so` file, and not
against some additional file generated at the same time.

The options `-Bstatic` and `-Bdynamic` only come into play when
both a `.so` and a `.a` are present, in the same directory; they
tell the linker which one to choose for libraries specified
using the `-l` option.  In Windows, this situation cannot occur;
since you need a `.lib` for the `.dll`, you cannot have a `.lib`
to be statically linked in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

> Because if file is .a file then I must be using static -linking and if file is .so I am using dynamic linking.

These filename "extensions" are only human conventions — there is no reason that they *have* to be `.a` and `.so` respectively. Quite rightly does GCC not force us into that convention.